# WordPress Check User Role Function (multiple roles)?

Tags: functions

I'm playing around with the [check_user_role function](http://docs.appthemes.com/tutorials/wordpress-check-user-role-function/) put together by AppThemes; as mentioned in the WordPress current_user_can codex page.  In the AppThemes tutorial code it references the following:

```
// example use for the current user
if ( appthemes_check_user_role( 'customer' )
    _e( "You've got access dude!", 'appthemes' );
else
    _e( "Sorry man, no luck.", 'appthemes' );
```

I'm wanting to get this to work with more than 1 user role (i.e. 'customrole', 'subscriber') but not having much luck without creating what feels like repetitive code.

The only way I got it to work was to do something like:

```
if (appthemes_check_user_role( 'customrole' ) || appthemes_check_user_role( 'author' ) ) {
    _e( "You've got access dude!", 'appthemes' );
} else {
    _e( "Sorry man, no luck.", 'appthemes' );
}
```

Or this:

```
if (appthemes_check_user_role( 'customrole' ) ) {
    _e( "You've got access dude!", 'appthemes' );
} if (appthemes_check_user_role( 'author' )) {
    _e( "You've got access dude!", 'appthemes' );
}else{
    _e( "Sorry man, no luck.", 'appthemes' );
}
```

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions to simplify the code for use with multiple roles?

Comment: Maybe creating your own function looping through an array of roles you send to that function?
if (my_cool_function(array('customrole','author')))

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( wpse_99666_check_user_roles( array( 'customrole', 'author' ) ) )
    _e( "You've got access dude!", 'appthemes' );
else
    _e( 'Sorry man, no luck.', 'appthemes' );


/**
 * Checks if a particular user has one or more roles.
 *
 * Returns true on first matching role. Returns false if no roles match.
 *
 * @uses get_userdata()
 * @uses wp_get_current_user()
 *
 * @param array|string $roles Role name (or array of names).
 * @param int $user_id (Optional) The ID of a user. Defaults to the current user.
 * @return bool
 */
function wpse_99666_check_user_roles( $roles, $user_id = null ) {

    if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) )
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    else
        $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( empty( $user ) )
        return false;

    $user_roles = (array) $user->roles;

    foreach ( (array) $roles as $role ) {
        if ( in_array( $role, $user_roles ) )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```